# How to save output image file in MATLAB...?

Tags: matlab-guide

I want to save my output image file in MATLAB.. is there any way to do it automatically..

For example:

if i use some filtering techniques, then i want to save output image automatically in current folder...

like:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

a=imread('cameraman.tif');
b=fspecial(a,'log');
figure,imshow(b);
```

So, b contains t he output and i want to save in folder automatically..
Is there any built in function or code available on net..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try "imwrite" function in MATLAB